# How to visible all the time 3 tab on PagerTabStrip?

Tags: android, android-viewpager, viewpagerindicator, viewpage

I have a android application which try to implement android PagerTabStrip on ViewPager.I have three tab 
1) Tab1 2)Tab2 and 3) Tab3. When Tab1 are selected then only show Tab1>>Tab2(pic_01).When Tab2 selected then it show Tab1>>Tab2>>Tab3(pic_02). When Tab3 selected then it show Tab2>>Tab3(pic_03).But I want ,all the time 3 tab will be visible at the same time. Such as when Tab1 selected then it will Tab3>>>Tab1>>Tab2. Same as when Tab2 selected then it will be ab1>>Tab2>>Tab3 .and when Tab3 slected then it will be Tab2>>Tab3>>Tab1.My trying cod are bellow which i implement.

```
   viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);        
    mPagerTabStrip = (PagerTabStrip)findViewById(R.id.PagerTab);
    mPagerTabStrip.setScrollContainer(true);
    // Set the ViewPagerAdapter into ViewPager
    viewPager.setAdapter(new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()));
```

ViewPagerAdapter is the FragmentPagerAdapter  class.

```
public class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

final int PAGE_COUNT = 3;
// Tab Titles
private String tabtitles[] = new String[] { "Tab1", "Tab2", "Tab3" };
Context context;

public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return PAGE_COUNT;
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {

    Log.w("position", "are:"+position);
    switch (position) {


        // Open FragmentTab1.java
    case 0:
        FragmentTab1 fragmenttab1 = new FragmentTab1();
        return fragmenttab1;

        // Open FragmentTab2.java
    case 1:
        FragmentTab2 fragmenttab2 = new FragmentTab2();
        return fragmenttab2;

        // Open FragmentTab3.java
    case 2:
        FragmentTab3 fragmenttab3 = new FragmentTab3();
        return fragmenttab3;
    }
    return null;
}

@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
    return tabtitles[position];
}
```

}

[image]

[image]

[image]

**Actually i want all the time those three tab will be visible same as pic_02.Is it possible?Please help to me.(Thanks to all)**

Answer (score 0):

Per [this answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27999644/1518546) I don't think it is possible with a `PagerTabStrip` to show all three tabs at the same time (except when on the second tab, of course). It looks like you'll have to use `ActionBar` or roll your own tab strip.