# PagerTabStrip - show all tabs on screen like a normal actionbar tab implementation?

Tags: android

I'm using PagerTabStrip with ViewPager:

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
    <android.support.v4.view.PagerTabStrip />
</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```

It seems the style of PagerTabStrip is different than the tab widget you use with the actionbar, in that the tab positions are not fixed. Is there a way to force that positioning/styling?

My pager only has two tabs, and it looks really silly to not have both tabs visible at once.

Thanks

Comment: I have a sample with 10 tabs and several tabs are visible at once. You might consider posting the actual layout file plus uploading a screenshot somewhere, to better explain your symptoms.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, tabs in `PagerTabStrip` don't work the way tabs in `ActionBar` do.
You can either use the `ActionBar` or create a custom strip.